# Firebase Object Size Validation

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-security

I'm allowing users to store complex objects to the realtime database but I'm worried about my storage quota given the possibility of shenanigans.  In previous projects I've been able to limit values by length by explicitly defining each key with a string length:

```
".validate": "newData.isString() && newData.val().length < 512"
```

However, my current object has a large number of nested keys and strings I'd rather just limit each object stored by 1MiB call it good.  Firebase is able to tally the database size and charge me accordingly, I'd like to access that in my calculations if possible.  Something like:

```
".validate": "newData.isObject() && newData.usage().storage < 1048576"
```

I'm trying to avoid creating a cloud function to check every write then `JSON.stringify(obj).length` process the length of each object and lock the account or something like that.  Is there a security rule I may be missing that could achieve limiting objects sizes?

Answer (score 1):

There is no built-in object size in security rules. Doing this in Cloud Functions with a call to `JSON.stringify()` seems the most logical way to go.

Comment: I was afraid that might be it. Using cloud functions to resolve the database storage issue could instead allow a user to instead deplete my functions allotment cascading the issue.  How would you prevent the data from being written to the database with the function like a validate statement would provide?

Answer (score 0):

If you have known schema, you can use `.validate`
You can help yourself with bolt compiler achieving complex types validation https://firebaseopensource.com/projects/firebase/bolt/